# Requiring the CPU to cache data using an offset (non consequtively)

Tags: caching

We all know that the following code will have low performace, since at each iteration the CPU will load the new element `s` from the RAM.

```
#define N a very large number
struct{
    float m;
    int x[N]
} S;

void main(){
  struct S s[elements];
  ...
     //working with data
     for (i=0; i<elements;i++){
         total+=s[i].m;
     }
 ...
}
```

If N is small, and the `elements` of kind `s` can be kept inside the cache, it is very fast. Otherwise, the CPU will always ask for the new element to the RAM.

Since the array s[k].x is not used inside the loop, soes a function, to ask the CPU to collect elements in the cache, let's say every `N*sizeof(int)` bytes exists?

In this way, the cache will contains all s[k].m variables, and so it may keep everything inside the cache.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pattern modern CPUs are capable of recognizing. Read [Optimizing Application Performance on Intel® Core™ Microarchitecture Using Hardware-Implemented Prefetchers](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/optimizing-application-performance-on-intel-coret-microarchitecture-using-hardware-implemented-prefetchers):

> **Hardware prefetcher**: The hardware prefetcher operates transparently, without programmer intervention, to fetch streams of data and instruction from memory into the unified second-level cache. The prefetcher is capable of handling multiple streams in either the forward or backward direction. It is triggered when successive cache misses occur in the last-level cache and a stride in the access pattern is detected, such as in the case of loop iterations that access array elements.